# How can I invoke thg (Tortoise HG command line) from the command line and wait for it to exit?

Tags: cmd, command

I would like to execute a command like the following, from the command line:

> thg commit

I would also like the command line to wait until thg has been closed before proceeding.

At the moment, this does not work, even if I use the following command instead:

> start /WAIT thg commit

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!

Here's the answer:

> thg commit --nofork